# Tagging and sorting core-data, many-to-many

Tags: objective-c, macos, core-data, tags

I'm trying to create a tag based sorting system. So far I have a many-to-many relationship between 'tag <<->> movies'. What I want is to be able to sort the movies different in different tags. How do I do this? Will core-data do this automatically when I check the ordered button in xcode?

image:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/y44p3o1m0vrrezi/preview.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this you have to insert a new entity between `MSTag` and `MSMovie` called e.g. `MSTaggedMovieDisplayOrder`:

```
MSTag <->> MSTaggedMovieDisplayOrder <<-> MSMovie
```

Then add a property `displayOrder` to the new entity with type `Integer`.

As this structure is heavier to handle I'd recommend to create a `Manager` class to manage:

1. Tagging a movie
2. Un-tagging a movie
3. Listing all tagged movies for a specific tag
4. Listing all tags for a specific movie
5. Moving tagged movie from display order to a new display order

With that you should be good to go.